# ember s - Port 4200 is already in use

Tags: ember.js

I have two ember projects: project1, project 2

project1: ember s  , port 4200 is working fine. I closed the project1 terminal and again tried to start ember s inside project2, when i do that, i am getting Port 4200 is already in use.

> Port 4200 is already in use.

Why am i getting this error, as other instances where already killed and how to rectify it ?

Comment: check port 4200 is listeneing or not ...use portqry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following,

```
sudo fuser -k 4200/tcp
```

It will kill all process belongs to port 4200.

Comment: If Node is more of your thing: `npx kill-port 4200`

Answer (score 11):

None of the answers work on Mac so I'm posting this solution.

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:4200 -t)
```

Answer (score 4):

I extended my comment as answer for windows user,

To see the 4200 is already in use or not, if so what process is holding port, run the below command

```
netstat -ano | findstr :4200
```

This will show some result like this,

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:4200           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12784
TCP    [::]:4200              [::]:0                 LISTENING       12784
```

which will list out list of processes using 4200 port. you can find process id in the result. in the above result pid is 12784 . We need to kill this process to free port.

```
TaskKill.exe /F /PID 12784
```

Answer (score 3):

The following solution works on Mac & Linux.

Try using:

```
ember serve --port 0
```

Per ember help: "Pass 0 to automatically pick an available port". (In a terminal, type `ember help`).

This approach can also work to run more than one ember site at the same time. It helps you find an available port as well as a different live-reload-port for each:

```
ember serve --port 0 --live-reload-port 0
```

If you get the same error in any of these cases, you can also enter the following python script at your Terminal prompt to identify an available port:

```
python -c 'import socket; s=socket.socket(); s.bind(("", 0)); print(s.getsockname()[1]); s.close()'
```

You can then specify ports you know to be available:

```
ember serve --port <known_port_1> --live-reload-port <known_port_2>
```

Comment: giving credit where credit is due, the python 1-liner is from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55913/whats-the-easiest-way-to-find-an-unused-local-port#comment271991_132524 - thanks for that, @lekensteyn !

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a solution, but I'm posting it anyway incase anyone suffers the same fate as me. All morning I've tried to boot an app on any port available, only to be met with `No open port found above 0`.

After a tonne of trial and error, **what fixed it was rebooting the Mac**. Even though it had only just done a fresh boot ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

UPDATE: it seems as though specifying a port and host in `.ember-cli` was affecting this. Oddly, if you specify the same values as command line arguments it works fine ¯_(ツ)_/¯